# C++ template and shadow parameter

Tags: c++, templates

I have one simple question. What is the reason of compilation failure?

```
template <class T>
class test
{
    T varGoodForNothing;
public:
    test()
    { }
    test(test<T> & tt)
    {
        varGoodForNothing = tt.varGoodForNothing;
    }
    test<T> & operator=(const test<T> & tt)
    {
        if (this == &tt)
            return *this;
        test(tt);
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Compiler error is:

> declaration of test tt shadows a parameter.

Comment: Change `test(tt);` to `this->test(tt);`.

Comment: @АнтонЕлькин That won't work.

Comment: Try not to implement copy constructor using the assignment operator and vice versa. Replace the line `test(tt);` with `this->varGoodForNothing = tt.varGoodForNothing;`.

Comment: @RSahu implementing `operator=` in terms of copy ctor is perfectly reasonable. In fact the copy and swap idiom is one of the best ways to overload the assigment operator, and just relies on the copy ctor.

Comment: It is safer to make the parameter type in the copy constructor to const test<T> & tt as well

Comment: @awesomeyi Why should he? It will compile, but it won't do what he wants.

Comment: @0x499602D2 You are right, that will not compile: one cannot call a constructor from a member function. I just wanted to give a hint how to "call" a constructor in this situation, which is what the author wanted. Sorry for misleading.

Comment: @0x499602D2 Wow, I never knew one could declare things with parentheses *only* around the identifier `int (a);`. Creepy..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### What does the standard say?

The standard says that a declaration of type `Type (name)` is the same has having used `Type name`, see the below standard quotation.

> **[dcl.meaning]** / 6
>
> In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>
> > ```
> > ( D1 )
> > ```
> >
> > The type of the contained *declarator-id* is the same as that of the contained *declarator-id* in the declaration `T D1`.
> >
> > Parentheses do not alter the type of the embedded *declarator-id*, but they can alter the binding of complex declarators.

<sup>With that said you are not calling the copy-constructor of `test` with an argument named `tt`, instead the compiler thinks that you are trying to declare a variable of type `test` with the **name** `tt`.</sup>

---

### How to get around the problem?

To circumvent the problem of `T (D);` being interpreted as `T d;` we will have to wrap `T` inside parentheses, such as in the below.

```
(test) (tt);
```

---

<sup>**Note:** Even if the code will compile after the proposed change it will not do what you want, nor think, it will.</sup>

<sup>Instead of calling the copy-constructor of `test` for the given instance you will declare an anonymous instance of `test` initialized with the value of `tt`.</sup>

<sup>Constructors can only be called from within other constructors (using a [member initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list)).</sup>

Comment: Doesn't your solution simply create a temporary of type `test`? It doesn't affect `this` at all (and thus no copy occurs on `this`).

Comment: @0x499602D2 I just edited the post to make this clear (see the section marked as *Note* ).

Comment: IT'S working... you are very good. But, I don't understand this principe. Can you please explaint it to me in detail?

Comment: @Seraph the added note together with everything else should make it reasonable clear, your original question has been answered. If you have a follow-up question please create a new question with that accurately specified.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is confused as to whether tt is the local variable (method parameter) or the name of a new test object. As 0x499602D2 mentioned, it's called [Most Vexing Parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

It's generally not good practice to call the copy constructor from the assignment operator and vice versa. Assign the member variables explicitly instead like:

```
this->varGoodForNothing = tt.varGoodForNothing;
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit. Replace test(tt) with the above. See http://ideone.com/2OFsXJ

Answer (score -1):

To ensure the absence of naming conflict in the stack just use:

> this.varGoodForNothing = tt.varGoodForNothing;

Comment: Doesn't answer the question: *"What is the reason of compilation failure?"*

Comment: Also `this` is a pointer, so the arrow operator has to be used here. `this->varGoodForNothing`